# Setting process priority (nice value) for `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` workers, cross-platform & elegant

Tags: python

The worker processes spawned by `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), tend to have the same priority as their main/parent process - to be expected. I was looking for "clean" options to start them with lower (lowest) possible priority for certain jobs without interfering with the main/parent process.

So far, I am using `psutil`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245096/1672565), and simply let an `initializer` function call change the process priority of the newly spawned worker processes "from within":

```py
import os
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from time import sleep
import psutil

def set_priority(value: int):
    p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    p.nice(value)
    
def task(item: int) -> int:
    sleep(2)
    return item ** 2

with ProcessPoolExecutor(
    max_workers = 2,
    initializer = set_priority,
    initargs = (19,),
) as executor:
    jobs = [executor.submit(task, item) for item in range(10)]
    data = [job.result() for job in jobs]

print(data)
```

Following up on the above, I considered deriving a `ProcessPoolExecutorNice` class from `ProcessPoolExecutor` with all magic hidden in it, generalizing this to a point where custom `initializer` functions can still be passed by a user.

A draft Unix-only solution looks as follows. `wrapper` uses name-space magic and is not perfectly serializable, a requirement for making this work on Windows as far as I understand the subject:

```py
import os
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import psutil

class ProcessPoolExecutorNice(ProcessPoolExecutor):
    def __init__(self, *args, nice: int = 0, **kwargs):
        assert len(args) <= 4 # HACK not future-proof
        initargs = args.pop(3) if len(args) == 4 else kwargs.pop('initargs', tuple())
        initializer = args.pop(2) if len(args) == 3 else kwargs.pop('initializer', None)
        def wrapper():
            self._set_priority(nice)
            if initializer is not None:
                initializer(*initargs)
        super().__init__(*args, initializer = wrapper, **kwargs)
    @staticmethod
    def _set_priority(value: int):
        p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        p.nice(value)
```

It can be tested as follows:

```py
from time import sleep

A = [-1]        

def prepare():
    A[0] = os.getpid()

def task(item: int) -> int:
    sleep(2)
    return item + A[0]

with ProcessPoolExecutorNice(
    max_workers = 2,
    initializer = prepare,
    nice = 19,
) as executor:
    jobs = [executor.submit(task, item) for item in range(10)]
    data = [job.result() for job in jobs]

print(data)
```

Is there a better, more elegant way of doing this, perhaps on the level of the `ProcessPoolExecutor` object? I looked through the docs - not sure if I am overlooking something.

My messing around with `initargs` and `initializer` arguments in `ProcessPoolExecutorNice`'s constructor can for sure be improved significantly - [another recent question of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/272070/20225) was aiming at that.

More to the point, `wrapper` is a bottle-neck when porting this thing. Ideas on how to approach something like this?